Design abstract data class with abstract class to manipulate these data
I have many class used only to store data. There are many fields in common. So, I created a structure.
Here is the code:
public class DepositMono extends DefaultDeposit {
    Long id;
    Periodic periodic;
}

//exist only to be able that type in the abstract service
public class  DefaultDeposit extends AbstractDeposit {

}

public abstract class AbstractDeposit {
    private Long idDeposit;
}

I created an Abstract service class to process field who exist for all the class.
public interface DepositInterface {
    AbstractDeposit fillDeposit(Deposit deposit);
}

public abstract class AbstractDepositService {

    protected AbstractDeposit prefillDeposit(Deposit deposit) {
        DefaultDeposit defautDeposit = mapper.toDto()...

        return defaultDepotPublication;
    }

}

public class MonoDepositService extends AbstractDepositService implement DepositInterface{
    @Override
    public AbstractDeposit fillDeposit(Deposit) {

        DepositMono depositMono = (DepositMono) prefillDeposit(deposit);

        return depotPublicationRecord;
    }
    
}

Actually in MonoDepositService, I get an error:DefaultDeposit cannot be cast to DepositMono
So, I search for a Design to be able to do a generic process in the abstract class and the rest of the specific process in the other class.
Generic could surely be a solution, any other alternative?

Hello Robert, without having the actual structure of data and methods, I can only suggest that you add in MonoDepositService the attributes of -DepositMono and create an interface that both implement.

An alternative would be an object-oriented approach. Right now you're using a procedural approach (data structures and services - procedures). In an object-oriented approach, you would put behavior inside objects, rather than putting it in services.

In Java, downcasting is not always possible, because there could be an issue of incompatibility. Let's suppose you have a Bird class and a subclass of Eagle and another subclass of Sparrow. now, if your Bird was instantiated as a Sparrow, then you will not be able to downcast it to an Eagle.
Your issue is that you instantiate the superclass and then attempt to downcast it to a subclass. Instead, you could create a class that has a generic in it and is capable of instantiating it, like:
public class GenericClass<T> {
    private T t;

    public GenericClass() {
        this.t = new T(); // DOES NOT COMPILE
    }

    public T getObject() {
        return t;
    }
}

Courtesy to https://www.baeldung.com/java-generic-type-instance-create
Surely, you can move this instantiation to the place that you desire and you can pass parameters too. So, you would do something like
GenericClass<MyClass> gc = new GenericClass<MyClass>();
MyClass myobject = gc.getObject();

